Mechanics of a contraction on the Kronecker product matrix
As a follow-up question to this one:
According to Wikipedia is the bases vectors are fixed the two tensors $A$ and $B$ result in the tensor product given by the Kronecker multiplication:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\small T = A \otimes B =\small
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} \otimes
\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} \\=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} & 
a_{1,2}\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} \\
a_{2,1}\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} &
a_{2,2}\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}b_{1,1} & a_{1,1}b_{1,2}\\
a_{1,1}b_{2,1} & a_{1,1}b_{2,2} \end{bmatrix} & 
\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,2}b_{1,1} & a_{1,2}b_{1,2}\\
a_{1,2}b_{2,1} & a_{1,2}b_{2,2} \end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}a_{2,1}b_{1,1} & a_{2,1}b_{1,2}\\
a_{2,1}b_{2,1} & a_{2,1}b_{2,2} \end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}a_{2,2}b_{1,1} & a_{2,2}b_{1,2}\\
a_{2,2}b_{2,1} & a_{2,2}b_{2,2} \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I presume that $T$ would have two upper and two lower indices, as in $T^{ij}_{\phantom{ij}kl}$.
Question:
If I want to contract (as in one of the comments to the prior post) $i$ and $l$, what would be the mechanics (algorithm) it if all I have is the final Kronecker block matrix above? (no $A$ or $B$ explicitly given).
I am not sure that I understand what contraction would mean in this set up, but since I know it is matrix multiplication, and that contraction means equating two indices, I think it could be calculated in matrix form as follows (not sure it's correct, please correct as needed):
$$\begin{matrix}
j = 1, k = 1: & T^{i1}_{\phantom{i1.}1i} = a_{1,1}b_{1,1} + a_{2,1}b_{1,2}\\
j = 1, k = 2: & T^{i1}_{\phantom{i1.}2i} = a_{1,1}b_{2,1} + a_{2,1}b_{2,2} \\
j = 2, k = 1: & T^{i2}_{\phantom{i2.}1i} = a_{1,2}b_{1,1} + a_{2,2}b_{1,2} \\
j = 2, k = 2: & T^{i2}_{\phantom{i2.}2i} = a_{1,2}b_{2,1} + a_{2,2}b_{2,2}
\end{matrix}
$$
or
$$
\begin{matrix}
i = l = 1 & i = l = 2\\
a_{{\color{red}1}j} b_{k{\color{red}1}} & a_{{\color{red}2}j} b_{k{\color{red}2}}\\
--- & ---\\
a_{11} b_{11} & a_{21} b_{12}\\
a_{11} b_{21} & a_{21} b_{22}\\
a_{12} b_{11} & a_{22} b_{12}\\
a_{12} b_{21} & a_{22} b_{22}
\end{matrix}
$$
which could be arranged in a matrix multiplication as:
$$Y^j_{\phantom{-}k}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{21}\\
a_{12} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{21}\\
b_{12} & b_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1}b_{1,1} + a_{2,1}b_{1,2} & a_{1,1}b_{2,1} + a_{2,1}b_{2,2} \\ a_{1,2}b_{1,1} + a_{2,2}b_{1,2} & a_{1,2}b_{2,1} + a_{2,2}b_{2,2} \end{bmatrix}$$
whether the sums in each entry of the final matrix make sense, I am not sure.

First a remark on the side: the distinction between upper and lower indices does not mean much in this context where we are not dealing with a metric; only the order of the indices matters.
The result of contracting over the first and fourth indices can be written as a square $2\times2$ matrix composed of four traces of $2\times2$ submatrices like in the previous question; for example, the $(j=1,k=1)$ component of the contraction is the trace of the submatrix consisting of elements in rows $1$ and $3$ and in columns $1$ and $2:$
$$a_{1,1}b_{1,1}+a_{2,1}b_{1,2}=\hbox{Tr}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}b_{1,1} & a_{1,1}b_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1}b_{1,1} & a_{2,1}b_{1,2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
For these two indices in particular, you correctly note that it can be interpreted as a matrix product but it may appear awkward that you have to write the transposes of the original matrices, and the result is transposed as well. These transpositions can be avoided if you switch the order of the matrices:
$$Y^{jk}=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}b_{1,1}+a_{2,1}b_{1,2} & a_{1,2}b_{1,1}+a_{2,2}b_{1,2} \\
a_{1,1}b_{2,1}+a_{2,1}b_{2,2} & a_{1,2}b_{2,1}+a_{2,2}b_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If you would contract over the middle indices $j$ and $k$ instead of $i$ and $l$ then the result corresponds to the usual definition of a matrix product without changing the order.

Thank you very much! Yes, I did transpose the matrices. Frankly, I still don't know if your convenient re-arrangement of the bock matrices on the prior answer was completely ad hoc to accommodate my request of keeping a matrix / basic lin alg solution, or followed a more systematic rearrangement (I'd be very interested in it). But in any case, I applied the first principle of ad hoc reshuffling to make it work - it is much more elegant now with the switching of the order in your answer.

Actually, I skimmed over your explanation on the prior answer: "The system behind rearranging the block matrices is that the grouping (in order to write the tensor as a 4×4 matrix) involves an arbitrary choice of two indices, and the contraction may be over a different pair of indices". You did already address the rearrangement. Thanks again!

There is always some arbitrariness in representing a rank $4$ tensor as a two-dimensional row/column arrangement. Two of the indices will indicate rows and columns within $2\times2$ submatrices, and the two other indices will index the submatrices themselves in the larger arrangement. If we know in advance that we are going to contract over $2$ of the $4$ indices than it helps to choose those indices to represent the dimensions of the inner $2\times2$ matrices.

Right! The tidy packaging is also constraining - it's order in rows and cols functions as a proxy for the basis vectors, but typically, this would be part of the tensor in a less constraining notation, such as $Y^{jk} e_{j} \otimes e_{k}$. At the end of these couple of questions / answers, it seems that there is no difference in the mechanics between contracting a tensor or tensor multiplying (for instance a tensor $\otimes$ (eating) a vector.

Another final reflection (slash prompt for you to comment upon) is that the reason why both this and the contraction in the prior question were boiled down to a sum (trace) is because the pair-wise multiplication had already occurred in the Kronecker $\otimes$.

Only that I agree with your last remarks. Matrix multiplication can be viewed very naturally as a contraction of a tensor product.
